# How to get all rows from related table using join in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have two tables. First table contain offer details and second table contains offer collection of languages(collection can be selected in main offer form). I want to use query with "join" language table to get all of them in single query. How it's look like:
[Relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR4nn.png)

Trying to get all of the offers I want to get all offer languages as one field.

```
     array [
      'id' => string '11',
      'name' => string '134',
      'date' => string '01-12-2016',
      'languages' => array(all language value from related table)
     ]
```

Here is my query:

```
        $select = $this->getDbTable()->select()
            ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
            ->from(array('o' => 'offers'), array('o.*'))
            ->joinLeft(array('ol' => 'offer_language'), 'ol.id_offer = o.id', array('ol.*'));

    $resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll($select)
```

In that way if one offer has a three language then I get three same offer with different language field.

Zend Version: 1.11

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a Zend_Db_Expr with GROUP_CONCAT.
Here are two posts that will give you a clear explanation:
[Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field) and [How to use GROUP_CONCAT with Zend Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329077/how-to-use-group-concat-with-zend-framework)

Your code will end up looking something like this:

```
$select = $this->getDbTable()->select()
          ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
          ->from(array('o' => 'offers'), array('o.*'))
          ->joinLeft(array('ol' => 'offer_language'), 'ol.id_offer = o.id', array('languages' => new Zend_Db_Expr('GROUP_CONCAT(ol.language)')))
          ->group('o.id');
```

Good luck!